# Problema ao enviar um arquivo por POST

Tags: php, html, mysql

O seguinte código que apresento há vocês logo abaixo é para fazer upload de um arquivo ".CSV" e mandar os dados para o MySQL, porém o método post não está mandando nada para a função .PHP, e recebo a  mensagem "vazio".

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Upload Estoque

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div align="center">
        <p>Upload CSV: <input type="file" name="file"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Importar"></p>
    </div>

</form>
```

```
<?php
    include "APIConnecting.php";

    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        if ($_FILES['file']['name']) {
            $arquivo = explode(";", $_FILES['file']['name']);
            if ($arquivo[1] == "csv") {
                $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
                while ($dados = fgetcsv($handle, 50)){
                    $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $dados[0]);
                    $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $dados[1]);
                    $sql = "INSERT INTO estoque (Chassi, Navio) VALUES ('$item1', '$item2')";
                    mysqli_query($con, $sql);
                }
                fclose($handle);
            }

        }
    }else{echo "vazio";}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

- Na linha 4 no qual verifica se há o POST você poderia colocar o campo File para garantir que o mesmo está sendo enviando um arquivo.
- Na Linha 6 você colocou ; (ponto-e-vírgula) o certo seria . (ponto) para pegar extensão.

Alterando apenas isso, testei aqui e deu certo.
O Código ficou assim:

```
if (isset($_FILES['file'])) { 
    if ($_FILES['file']['name']) {
        $arquivo = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
        if ($arquivo[1] == "csv") {
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "r");
            while ($dados = fgetcsv($handle, 50)){
                $item1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $dados[0]);
                $item2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $dados[1]);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO estoque (Chassi, Navio) VALUES ('$item1', '$item2')";
                if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){
                  echo "Salvo com Sucesso.";
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }

    }
}else{echo "vazio";}
```

Comment: Como ficou seu html? aqui ainda não ta dando certo, não está passando pela primeira condição. Está retornando vazio.